# How do I allow html tags in label for Zend form element using addElement()?

Tags: zend-framework, escaping, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I am brand new to Zend and I've been given a project to make adjustments on. I'd like to add html to the labels for my form elements but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's what I have:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'school_name', array(
    'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', false, array(0, 150)),
        ),
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'Name* :<img src="picture.png">,
    'size' => '90',
));
```

As is, of course, the `<img src="picture.png">` text gets escaped and the whole string is displayed.

I've read that I need to use `'escape' => false` in some capacity but I can't figure out where/how to use it in my specific case.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After calling `addElement` fetch the label's decorator and change the escape setting:

`$form->getElement('school_name')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);`

If you use this type of label a lot, you should consider [writing a custom decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919200/zend-form-add-span-to-label).

Comment: It didn't work. If I'm reading my debugger right (which I may not be), it looks like it's setting escape to false properly but it still is showing the full HTML on the page.

Comment: the code I used was `$this->getElement('school_name')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);`

Comment: Ah, figured it out. I needed to put that code in the .phtml file and not in the constructor. Got it.

Comment: I was able to do it also before adding the element

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the disable_html_escape in 'label_options' when adding an element to the form:

```
$this->add(array(
    ....
    'options' => array(
        'label' => '<span class="required">Name</span>,
        'label_options' => array(
             'disable_html_escape' => true,
         )
     ),
    ...
));
```

Credit to [Théo Bouveret's post 'Button content in ZF2 forms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776915/button-content-in-zf2-forms) for the answer.