# zend2 icon in button

Tags: php, zend-framework2, icons

I've found nice solution, but unfortunatley Zend2 return error

solution: 
[Button content in ZF2 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776915/button-content-in-zf2-forms/21778957#21778957)

error:

> Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving
>   "formbutton(alias: formbutton)" via invokable class
>   "MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormButton"; class does not exist

in MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormButton i've created FormButton.php:

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormButton as ZendFormButton;
class FormButton extends ZendFormButton
{    
    public function render(ElementInterface $element, $buttonContent = null)
    {
        $content = (isset($buttonContent)) ? $buttonContent : $element->getLabel();
        $icon    = isset($element->getOption('icon')) ? $element->getOption('icon') : '';

        $escape = $this->getEscapeHtmlHelper();

        return $this->openTag($element).$icon.$escape($content).$this->closeTag();
    }   
}
```

and Module.php:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'form_button' => 'MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormButton',
            )
        );
    }
```

inside ProductForm.php

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Button',
    'name' => 'submit',
    'options' => array(
        'label'   => 'Modifica',
        'icon'    => '<i class="icon icon-foo">',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-warning'
    )
));
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the full path to your helper class is? The error means ZF can't find this class.

Comment: Do you have the namespace declaration `namespace MyModule\Form\View\Helper` at the top of the class? You will also need to ensure your modules' classes are autoloaded using `getAutoloaderConfig()` method in `Module.php`.

Comment: @AlexP I'v not added declaration, but adding nothing change.

Comment: @Tim Fountain: The path is: MyModule\Form\FromButton.php, and I have changed it in getViewHelperConfig(), but without result. Error is still appear

Comment: The file should be at `module/MyModule/src/MyModule/Form/View/Helper/FormButton.php`, the invokable is correct as it is in your question now. You do need the namespace declaration. If it still doesn't work, please update your question with the changes you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. using its `disable_html_escape` flag value as `true`.

```
$this->form->add(array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
     'name' => 'agreement_point',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => $this->getTranslatorHelper()->translate('Ich akzeptiere die <a class="first-agreement">Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingunge</a>, die <a class="second-agreement">Wiederrufsbedingungen</a> und'),
            'label_options' => array(
            'disable_html_escape' => true,
        ),
     )
));
```